# How to start async processing in onPost method in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, backgroundworker, servicestack

I have a simple app that processes a file submitted from form. I'm trying to run file processing asynchronously with code listed below.

Unfortunately, http response is returned, after long-running `StaticProcessingMethod` has finished.

What is the proper way of processing file asynchronously on submit?

```
public override object OnPost(Item item)
{
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += new System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventHandler(
        delegate(object o, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
        {
            StaticProcessingMethod(base.RequestContext.Files[0].InputStream);
        });

    worker.RunWorkerAsync();

    return new HttpResult("Processing started", ContentType.PlainText + ContentType.Utf8Suffix);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a single background thread wrapped and injected as a dependency that just queues a list of tasks it needs to processs. e.g. something like:

```
public IBackgroundProcessor BackgroundProcessor { get; set; }

public object Post(Item item)
{
    BackgroundProcessor.Enqueue(
      new StaticProcessingTask(item, base.RequestContext.Files[0].InputStream));

    return new HttpResult("Processing started", 
        ContentType.PlainText + ContentType.Utf8Suffix);
}
```

The background thread is started in the AppHost. Enqueuing a task will enqueue it on a Concurrent Queue and Notify/Wake the background sleeping thread, otherwise if the bg thread is still running it goes to sleep after processing all pending tasks.

Note: the sample code above makes use of [ServiceStack's improved New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api).